# Address out of bounds

Tags: c, kernel

```
crash --- cir_debug_log
cir_debug_log = $7 = {
buffer = 0xac3d83097f040056 <Address 0xac3d83097f040056 out of bounds>, 

crash --- print *cir_debug_log->buffer
Cannot access memory at address 0xac3d83097f040056
gdb: gdb request failed: print *cir_debug_log->buffer
crash ---
```

---

Here i have defined a global structure

```
typedef struct circular_buffer 

char            *buffer;
unsigned        capacity;
unsigned        head_offset;
unsigned        tail_offset;
volspin_t       vxl_lock;

extern struct circular_buffer cir_debug_log;
```

And I am initialing it driver load time also tracking its address through out the process which is not changing.

```
cb->buffer : mzalloc_sleep(25000* sizeof(char));
```

But somehow I am not able to print the string which is present in cir_debug_log->buffer through CRASH. It is properly copying the string in this buffer which i have checked. 
address of cb->buffer is not changing but in the crash it is showing different address.

---

```
cb_push_data: end trying to print messgae with cb->buffer contains buffer_content=
"Purging msg accumulated during reonline operation "
```

This is my string which should print through crash also.

---

Here is my question ::

1. I am never changing the address of this buffer. For storing purpose i am using the tail offset (like this *(cb->buffer + cb->tail_offset) = ch; and increasing the tail_offset like this cb->tail_offset = (++cb->tail_offset)%cb->capacity;
2. I am curious about the content of capacity, head_offset and tail_offset. Please look at the crash o/p.

crash-- cir_debug_log 
cir_debug_log : $7 :  buffer -- 0xac3d83097f040056 , capacity -- 67131560, 
head_offset -- 2303465086, 
tail_offset -- 1156221409, 
vxl_lock -- 000

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "address of cb->buffer is not changing but in the crash it is showing different address"? Some part of your code (or - less likely - some other driver in the kernel) might be corrupting `cir_debug_log` and overwriting the `buffer` pointer value with garbage. That value (ending in 0x56) looks a little odd for what you've malloc'ed.

Comment: Here is my question ::  1. I am never changing the address of this buffer. For storing purpose i am using the tail offset (like this *(cb->buffer + cb->tail_offset) = ch; and increasing the tail_offset like this cb->tail_offset = (++cb->tail_offset)%cb->capacity;         2. I am curious about the content of capacity, head_offset and tail_offset. Please look at the crash o/p. crash> cir_debug_log
cir_debug_log = $7 = {
  buffer = 0xac3d83097f040056 <Address 0xac3d83097f040056 out of bounds>, 
  capacity = 67131560, 
  head_offset = 2303465086, 
  tail_offset = 1156221409, 
  vxl_lock = { }

Comment: Certainly looks like the struct has been trashed. Given that you malloc'ed 25,000 bytes those values don't make sense. Unfortunately I don't have any tips for kernel driver debugging.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Andrew.

Answer (score 0):

```
I see you have this code displayed, which is missing most of the initialization 
and what is displayed contains some syntax errors

typedef struct circular_buffer 
{ // this line is missing
char            *buffer;
unsigned        capacity;
unsigned        head_offset;
unsigned        tail_offset;
volspin_t       vxl_lock;
} // this line is missing

extern struct circular_buffer cir_debug_log;


// where is this declaration of 'cb'?
struct circular_buffer *cb = cir_debug_log; 

// where is the initialization of the other fields?
cb->capacity = 25000 * sizeof(char);
cb->head_offset = 0;
cd->tail_offset = 0;

// this has a syntax error: ':' should be '='
cb->buffer : mzalloc_sleep(25000* sizeof(char)); 


BTW:
it is normal to write to the *head* and read from the *tail*.
```